# How to Authenticate Google Api using client id and client secret only

Tags: authentication, google-bigquery

I am trying to access Google Big Query API using Desktop Application Knime. Is there any way that google can directly authenticate me without requiring any further action if i provide client id and client secret. I think its possible because i have seen it in another application but i don't know the exact URL that was used to authenticate in that application.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you've seen this with some app that supports [interoperability-mode](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/interoperability) access to Google Cloud Storage. To authenticate with BigQuery (or any other Cloud Platform related API), you will need to thru either service-account authorization (server-to-server) or OAuth (client to server).

If Knime is a desktop application (not web application), they might support 'Installed and desktop applications' authentication. Applications that use an installed flow require that the application has access to the system web browser, or the ability to embed a browser control in the application. During the authorization flow, the application redirects the user to a Google-hosted webpage to request access to the BigQuery API on their behalf. If access is granted, the page will provide an access code that must be given to the application to complete the BigQuery authorization grant.

You can read on a BigQuery authentication [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/authentication?hl=en).